# iTextSharp characters č and ž (Foxit vs Adobe reader)

Tags: pdf, encoding, itext

I hope someone can help me.

I am writing some application that need to print pdfs.

After long search i found out how to properly print character for Slovenian language.

i did it this way:

```
    iTextSharp.text.Font crkeMaleCrneBold = 
            FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER,
                                BaseFont.CP1250,
                                8,
                                iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD,
                                new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0));
```

Everything works gr8 on Foxit Reader but in Adobe Reader X i se crossed square when using CP1250 and When IDENTITY_H i see missing character..

I think PDF did get the desired character č but adobe doesn't print it well.

What is the proper Encoding to use slovenian character? I don't have time to generate some in latex to see what is happening there...

Answer (score 4):

Again I am answering my own question :=)

There is solution for you guys

First I created: (note full path to .ttf, else there is error)

```
BaseFont arial = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

... and as you se i used IDENTITY_H instead of CP1250

```
iTextSharp.text.Font crkeMaleCrne = new iTextSharp.text.Font(arial, 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
```

It works OK in Foxit & Adobe Reader. Finally ;=)
Now I think I will have to put arial.ttf to bin folder and distibute it with app to make sure user have the font?

Or I have to put it in win/font folder and register font to use it?

Comment: Arial ships with windows machines.  You can also use `FontFactory.registerDirectories()` and `FontFactory.getFont()` rather than calling BaseFont.CreateFont directly.  RegisterDirectories will look through all the standard font storage paths for a variety of OSes, and from there you can use their names instead of their paths.

Comment: PS: If you wish to include a custom font, you can put it anywhere.  Just be sure you have distribution rights for the font.  Their licenses tend to be quite particular.